# Error running simple selenium script with ruby: <main>': undefined local variable or method `‘selenium'

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to run my first selenium webdriver script using ruby. I have ruby installed, as well as the gem for webdriver. Googling this question for several hours has been fairly fruiteless - any help is appreciated!

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Hello WebDriver!"
element.submit

puts driver.title

driver.quit
```

I get this error message:

```
testb.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `‘selenium' for main:Object (NameError)
```

ruby -v 
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]

gem list returns selenium-webdriver (2.40.0) as part of the list

Can someone guide me a little? I think ruby simply isn't recognizing selenium and can't get past the second line of code - is there another step to 'link up' selenium with this simple ruby script?

Comment: what is written in line#2 ? I am not seeing anything.. Your current code is working

Comment: error is from a file *testb.rb*..

Comment: The error is from running the code above. I am running Mavericks OS X. Line 2 should be driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

Answer (score 5):

Line two was using single quotes (') rather than double for "selenium-webdriver". This is fixed.

Comment: This answer helped me, because the top google example has the single-quote mistake in it http://seleniumtutorials.com/2013/09/25/selenium/ruby-selenium-webdriver-tutorial-part-1-writing-our-first-test/